# What is the name of this Macromedia Shockwave game with a small plumber unclogging pipes from the inside?

Tags: game-identification, flash

This was a Macromedia Shockwave game I played online, which was likely made before 2008.

[image: A screenshot of the game in question, showing a small character standing inside grey pipes. Around him, we can notice stuck water dropplet, plungers, and yellow circles that are clogging the pipes. An arrow points down, hinting that the water should flow down that way]

The gameplay was pretty straightforward: we had to unclog the pipes and help all the water flow down. If any water remained stuck, or if the character died (shocked by a power outlet), you lost a life and eventually lost if you ran out of life.

The website on which I played it (when it existed) merely called it "Plumber" (although it's likely that they made up that name; most of the games they hosted didn't have the original name as displayed when you launched them). Unfortunately, the game wasn't archived on Archive.org.

Does someone remember the name of that game by any chance?

Comment: 'Plumber' is generally a rotation puzzle/math game that's been made and remade for countless platforms. Like [this one for flash](https://archive.org/details/1100_plumber) *[archive.org]*

Comment: Suddenly I wonder if I should remove the flash tag. An answer to a different question mentioned they're 2 completely different technologies (although I always had the impression shockwave games required flash too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is called *Puny Plumber*.

I did a Google Image Search for your screenshot, which found me the website of its developer, [Pizmo Games](http://www.pizmogames.com/misc/screenshots/).  Their copy of the screenshot is called "punyplumber2.gif".

Searching "Puny Plumber" will find you various Flash/Shockwave game sites that claim to have the game, although I wasn't able to run it.  Here's an example: https://www.gameitnow.com/Puny-Plumber-online.

Comment: The first link seems accurate. The second sends me to a page with game adds that have nothing to do with pipes, and it looks very much like if I click on one I'll be scrubbing my phone for the next hour or so..

Comment: Found the direct link for the game here: https://www.flashgames.jp/Puny-Plumber-online note that it is a flash game; officially, you can't play flash games since Adobe released the flash player killswitvh at the start of this year.

Comment: @Gnemlock Don't worry, I have the standalone Flash runner on my computer which can still run locally downloaded flash content. And thanks a lot to both of you for finding it. A reversed image search didn't yield anything for me for some strange reasons.

Comment: As I suspected, it's not an actual "Flash" game but a "Macromedia Shockwave" one. Using the official "dead" Pizmo link, I went on Archive.org, and here's the *.dcr file. You need a browser that still support Macromedia Shockwave to run it: https://web.archive.org/web/20040917014859/http://www.pizmogames.com/games/punyplumber/punyplumber.dcr

Comment: The category page does indeed send me to a list of pipe games (including Puny Plumber) when I use Firefox on PC - but when I tested the link on mobile (Chrome) it was a list of random games.  Strange.  I wanted to include that page, since the direct link is meaningless unless you have Shockwave enabled (there's no screenshot where the game should be), but as @Clockwork has confirmed it, I will delete this link.  I think both our direct links go to the same company; the website design is identical.